# Regarding scanf and many values to input

Tags: c

So I'm trying to solve this http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/sum-in-loop and I have 45 random numbers to input. I'm coding using C so I want to use the scanf function. The problem is that since it's 45 numbers (which are separated by spaces) what I want to do is copy paste the values so that the program can solve them from an array. Should I do it like this:

`int x [45];
scanf("%d %d....(x42) %d",&x,&x,...(x42),&x);`

or is there a more efficient way of doing this? (I hope there is T_T)

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; i < 45; i++){scanf(" %d", &x[i]);}`?

Comment: Notice that you don't need an array to solve the problem you linked since you just need to compute the sum of the numbers that are scanned. In a for loop, add the scanned number to the sum and forget it !

Answer (score 0):

You need not (and you should not) write a single format string containing 45(or whatever) format specifier, following 45 pointers.

You need to use a loop.

Example:

- `for` loop with an array, will hold the supplied operands, too

  ```
  int x[45] = {0};
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)    //style supported over C99
  {
     scanf("%d", &x[i]);
     sum += x[i];
   }
  printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
  ```
- `for` loop without an array, won't hold the operands, only result

  ```
  int x = 0;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)    //style supported over C99
  {
      scanf("%d", &x);
      sum += x;
   }
  printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
  ```

Comment: Hey, I found the brace you lost: `}`!

Comment: @EOF ha ha, take the other pair from my side as a gift, `{`

Comment: `int main(){
    int sum = 0;
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &x[i]);
        sum = sum + x[i];
        }
}`
How come I'm getting an invalid types `int[int]` for array subscript error?

Comment: @Eric change `int x = 0;` to `int x[45] = {0};` You need an array.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it much better now!